# AngularJS $resource: create custom POST action that gets an Array back

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, post, resources

I am trying to create a custom POST action using $resource in AngularJS, because the built-in $save() action does not accept array as the response.

The data I need to POST to the service is an array of names:

```
var namesArr = {"names" : ["Tom", "John", "Nick"]}
```

The service will return an array of the Person objects that match the names:

```
[TomObj, JohnObj, NickObj]
```

I tried the $save() method, but it does not accept array as the response:

```
var namesResource = $resource('myServiceUrl');
return new namesResource(namesArr).$save(); //return a promise
```

So I tried to create a custom action that first does POST, and returns an array in its response. The following code does not work, so I am seeking help with where might be wrong:

```
var customNameResource = $resource('myServiceUrl', {}, {
                retrieve: {method: 'POST', params: {}, isArray: true}
            });



            return new customNameResource(namesArr).$retrieve(); //return a $promise
```

**Edit:** The service supports all regular REST methods like GET, POST, PUT, DELETE

Comment: Have you considered using `$http` for this? `$resource` is kind of opinionated about what types of responses are permitted for REST-type requests.

Comment: yes, I use $http.post() as a temporary solution now, but would like to learn to create a custom action using $resource. thanks